# Google Maps SDK iOS house numbers at custom zoom level

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

Google Maps SDK for iOS shows house numbers only at zoom level ~17.0.
How to force it shows them at zoom level i want?

Comment: Have u tried setting the camera to a zoom level past the 17? [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views) will be helpful on how to do it

Comment: I meant it shows houses numbers at zoom 17 and so on until 20. This zoom level is too zoomed so user can't interact with map and houses numbers easily as i wish them to

Comment: You can still use the method to set the camera view to whatever zoom level you so please.

Comment: You don't understand me. My default app zoom is 15.0. At this level you can see terrain and streets with it names. When you zoom in (zoom level 17+) you can see the same but already with house numbers and when you zoom out (less then level 17) house number disappears from the map. I need to control this in code so that users can see house numbers at my default zoom level which is 15.0 because 17.0 is too close to the ground

Comment: I stand to be corrected but I don't think its possible to achieve what you want directly from the API because each zoom level, reveals certain [attributes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#MapOptions) of the map.

One way around this is to trigger a separate thread that'll load the map at zoom level 17; without showing this to the user, grab the respective markers at that level and simply add them to your map at level 15.